# Library to create and upload jar dynamically to maven repository

Tags: maven, jar, maven-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I have service based environment in which I have to create a jar and upload it dynamically to maven repository and return the dependency tree for it. Is there any library which will create a jar file and upload that jar file to maven repository and will return me dependecny of uploaded jar. Right now Im creating it with maven goals in eclipse but I don't want that.

Thanks,

Comment: mvn install is not enough ?

Comment: But its from command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use the command line or IDE, have you looked at the Maven API? There's also an 'undocumented' [Maven embedder](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.2/maven-embedder/) project.

Below are some links that may help you get started, pick the approach that is easier for you, while meeting your requirements:

- https://github.com/jenkinsci/lib-jenkins-maven-embedder/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/maven/MavenEmbedder.java
- http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.2/maven-embedder/apidocs/org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli.html
- http://q4e.googlecode.com/svn-history/r819/trunk/plugins/maven/core/src/org/devzuz/q/maven/embedder/internal/EclipseMaven.java
- http://developers-blog.org/blog/def../2009/09/18/How-to-resolve-an-artifact-with-maven-embedder

Comment: Thanks, also we can use maven invoker for that to execute goals from java code.